# WiFi not working on Asus Q503UA Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, xubuntu, asus

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 on an Asus Q503UA-BHI5T16.  It has an Intel wireless 7265 driver.  WiFi works in Windows.  But when I installed Xubuntu (completely getting of Windows), it doesn't work.

I've tried Fn+F2 but nothing happens.  Nor does this code fix the problem:

```
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
```

The trackpad isn't working either.  But I can't fix that until I have internet.

I'm familiar with command line but am a beginner @ Linux so please explain everything step-by-step.

Thank you,

AnneMarie

p.s. Here's the info on my computer:

```
lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2
```

03:00.0 Network Controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a](rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless -AC 7265 [8086:5110]

```
rfkill list all
```

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl
```

[10.655640] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: irq 144 for MSI/MSI-X 
[10.657368] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[10.657372] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[10.748013] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
[10.748017] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Falling back to user helper
[10.752405] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7265.7.ucode' failed.
[10.752452] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Comment: Your device is driven by the driver *iwlwifi*; however, in 14.04, I doubt that the driver version covers your rather new device. Let's do some diagnostics. Please edit your question to add the results of the following terminal commands: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `rfkill list all` and finally: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwl`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Hi!  Thank you for offering to help.  I added the info to my original message.  ~ AnneMarie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we see, your driver needs but cannot find the needed firmware. Let's try to find and install it.

Please download this file on some other computer and transfer it to the desktop of the Ubuntu computer with a USB stick of similar: https://github.com/OpenELEC/iwlwifi-firmware/archive/master.zip

Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-firmware-master/firmware
sudo cp iwlwifi-7265*  /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Your wireless should now be working.

Comment: Please confirm that you have a working internet connection: `ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com` Also, open Software and Updates and confirm that the sources, *main, universe, restricted and multiverse* are selected. Then try again.

Comment: I will edit my question in a few minutes.

Comment: It now says Wi-Fi Networks Available - Use the network menu to connect to a Wi-Fi network.  (Good sign!)  I went to Settings Manager > Network Connections but can't see my wireless network in the list.

Comment: It is referring to the Network Manager icon at the top: https://lafibre.info/images/tuto/201104_ubuntu_wifi.png

Comment: You should have something up there unless NM is not running as expected. http://www.socsci.uci.edu/~jstern/uci_vpn_ubuntu/systray2.png Does it appear if you issue, in the terminal: `nm-applet &`  ?

Comment: It says [1] 1958 and the next line says ?: command not found.  It put two of those two arrows icons on the top, both of which are greyed out.  (One was there before typing the line in the terminal.  It was greyed out.)

Comment: The two arrows *are* the Network Manager icon. Click it and see if you can click on 'Enable wireless.'  http://i.stack.imgur.com/FJawc.png   BTW. the ? was part of my sentence, not the command. Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: Oh geez.  I see now that ? wasn't part of the code I should have typed.  And I also see that when I click the greyed out arrows, the menu displays.  I feel a bit silly.  But I'm now online!  Thank you for your patience!!!  And for getting me sorted out with internet connection.  I just installed the update ($ sudo apt-get update) and it worked!!!  Thank you again!!!!

Comment: Glad it's working by whatever means. Have fun!

Comment: Because of you I didn't throw my computer out the window.  Thanks again!!!